# Ruby and SQL Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I connecting to SQL Server without making any ODBC connection. I am coming form.NET, so I am looking for something like a connection string with integrate security.

I don't know what is wrong with connection setting here. Please help!

```
development:
 adapter: sqlserver
  database: odbc
   dsn: Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.;Database=RubyDemo;Trusted_Connection=yes;
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000   
 test:
  adapter: sqlserver
   database: odbc
    dsn: Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.;Database=RubyDemo;Trusted_Connection=yes;
      pool: 5
     timeout: 5000 

      production:
      adapter: sqlserver
          database: odbc
        dsn: Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.;Database=RubyDemo; Trusted_Connection=yes;
 pool: 5
      timeout: 5000



 ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
 ** Invoke environment (first_time)
 ** Execute environment
 ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
 ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
  ** Execute rails_env
  ** Execute db:load_config
 rake aborted!
couldn't parse YAML at line 21 column 12
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application   /configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record   /railtie.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
   c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
         c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
       c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
     c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
      c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
     c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
     c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
      c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
   c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
     c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
   c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
 c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
   c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
  c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like a YAML parsing problem/syntax error long before it gets around to trying to connect to the database.  Is the indentation in the YAML file actually correct?  Where's the rest of the YAML - there aren't 21 lines in that excerpt?

Comment: update the image. Now you can see line 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an indentation problem in your YAML.  `production` should not be indented more than `test`.